# What is Address Binding?

Tags: virtual-memory, memory-management

I have found [some explanations about what "address binding"](https://www.quora.com/What-is-address-binding-in-memory-management) is. They say that "address binding is an operation of mapping virtual or logical addresses to physical addresses."

Is this definition correct?

I cannot make sure whether it is correct or not because a university presentation says that converting virtual addresses to physical addresses is performed in execution time. However, address binding says that binding operation can be implemented in compile time, load time or execution time.

This shows that there is a contradiction.

Comment: Might depend on the context. Can you add any links to the explanations you refer to?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-address-binding-in-memory-management

Comment: oh dear, that explanation seems somewhat confused, or at least confusing.

Comment: I think that address binding is generally performed in execution time. Binding in other steps is not preferred much. Thus, the presentation can make a generalization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The explanation on Quora seems to me to be rather confusing, and mixes up a number of concepts.

The term “address binding”, in the context of memory addresses (as opposed to network addresses for example), comes from [Leon Presser and John R. White’s 1972 paper on linkers and loaders](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~kubitron/cs162/hand-outs/p149-presser-linker-loader.pdf) (see also the [ACM entry](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=356605)), where it is defined as follows:

> The translation or mapping of a logical into a physical address is called *address binding*.

A quick read could give the impression that this is talking about logical and physical addresses from a memory management perspective, but that’s not the case; in the paper, physical addresses are addresses of “information” in memory, and logical addresses are the symbols used to refer to that information. Thus address binding is what is commonly referred to nowadays as symbol (or pointer) relocation, and as you say, this can happen at compile time (when generating a static binary for example), at load time (when the dynamic linker resolves symbols in a shared library), or at execution time (when the running program resolves symbols manually, *e.g.* using `dlopen`).

Comment: The reason why the code below prints same address values is that general purpose computers make address binding in execution time ? https://plus.google.com/photos/photo/116453553007996852896/6558716164175241938

Comment: No, the code you show prints the same address because the parent and child share the same virtual address space (which maps to different physical address spaces).

Comment: What I am trying to say is if the binding is performed in compile time or load time, I think we see the physical addresses instead of virtual address when the code is executed.

Comment: No, you wouldn’t see physical addresses in this context. The running code uses virtual addresses, and the CPU (MMU) maps them to physical addresses.

Comment: ... and *that* mapping (from virtual to physical) isn’t referred to as address binding (at least, I’ve never seen it called that).

Answer (score 0):

That article is confusing. The very first part of it article seems accurate. [Virtual addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) are used by CPU core, they're mapped by the MMU to physical addresses, and then those are used when going to RAM. I've never heard that being called "address binding", though. "Mapping" would be more common, but that's just a terminology issue.

Then there's this claim in the middle of the second paragraph, referring the above process:

> This type of binding requires the compiler to generate relocatable or offset based addresses from the source code.

That's nonsense.

Relocatable, or [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) is required in the situation where the program code doesn't know the virtual address it's located in, but needs to somehow take into account that it could be placed anywhere in virtual memory. This has nothing to do with physical address, since the program code running on the system has no knowledge of those. All addresses it sees are virtual address.

[Shared libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries) and [address-space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) are the two common cases where position-independent code is required. It does require support from the compiler, since the code must be built so that it cannot contain any absolute memory addresses, but instead makes all accesses relative to its own position or relative to some base position stored in a register.

All of that happens within the process's view of the virtual address space. It needs compiler support since the code itself needs to be aware of it.

Virtual address translation by the MMU *doesn't* require cooperation from the process. Instead it's the job of the OS to fix the address mappings as necessary, e.g. if part of the process is paged out to swap, and needs to be accessed.

[Segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) was also mentioned, it works pretty much like the article explains, except that at least on x86, segmentation produces *virtual* addresses, so the virtual-to-physical memory mapping happens after it.

<sub>(All of the above is based in what I know about x86 systems. Other systems might be different.)</sub>